# Hide on right click option in jwplayer

Tags: javascript, jwplayer, jwplayer6

**In Chrome:**
If I right click on jwplayer video, I can seen only one option "About jwplayer 6.12.."
[image]

**But In Internet Explorer:**
There are total 4 options are showing:

- About jwplayer 6.12..
- Settings
- Global Settings
- About Adobe flash player 19.0.0.226

[image]

How can I hide last 3 options in Internet Explorer ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't, sorry. It's up to Internet Explorer's source code what it displays when a Flash or HTML5 video element is right-clicked.

Comment: Yes exactly.. I asked jwplayer team. They told the same. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

A trick is adding this rule to your CSS:

```
.jw-rightclick { display: none !important; }
```

This will hide HTML-generated jwplayer right click menu, but not in Internet Explorer.

This does fully not resolve the question, but it will help another users that finds the question related to the title of this post.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible but you need a license in order to do so.
https://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/articles/1406865-branding-your-player

Comment: no @zer00ne, actually I want to remove flash related options from right click. I asked jwplayer team. They told it's because of IE.

Comment: that link 404s now